# Algorithm for triggering different activities based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, python, c#, list, algorithm

I have 5 checkboxes.

- Activity 1
- Activity 2
- Activity 3
- Activity 4
- Activity 5

and a Submit button.

Selecting Activity 1 alone, and onSubmit should trigger first activity.
Selecting Activity 1 & 2, and onSubmit should trigger first activity and then Second activity.
Selecting Activity 1,3 & 5, and onSubmit should trigger first activity then third activity and then fifth activity.

So there are total 31 different combinations in which the activity could be triggered.

1,2,3,4,5,
12,13,14,15,
23,24,25,
34,35,
45,
123,124,125,
134,135,
145,
234,235,245,
345,
1234,1235,1245,1345,
2345,
12345

What the best coding/algorithm to handle this scenario rather than using if else with subcondtions like below?

```
if (Checkboxvalue.contains("Activity1")) 
{
//trigger activity1 

  if (checkboxvalue.contains("Activity2"))
  {
   //trigger activity2
  }
  else if (checkboxvalue.contains("Activity3"))
  {
  //trigger activity3
  }...
}....
...
and so on
```

Comment: What is wrong with having the 5 if's after another without the else and layering, doesn't that do what you want?

Comment: Are these activities synchronous or asynchronous? If asynchronous, are they promise based? If not, what is the problem (when you drop the `else`)? Why no reaction to the previous comment?

Comment: modified the question. Actually these activities will be triggered onSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just have the code run (something similar to this code) as an OnClick Method that way solving the problem of the order.
Then have something like this;

```
private void RunActivity(string Activity)
{
    switch (Activity)
    {
        case "Activity 1":
            Activity1();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```